# executing script lines with another user and access to that user's $HOME

Tags: bash

I found a lot of solutions for parts of that problem, but not for the combination. So here is the plan:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "current home »$HOME«"
sudo -u git -H /bin/bash << END_OF_SCRIPT
  GitToolsRepo=$HOME/git-tools
  echo "using git tools at »$GitToolsRepo«"
END_OF_SCRIPT
echo finally
```

running this script with sudo as auser, unfortunately this always puts

```
current home »/home/auser«
using git tools at »«
finally
```

Assuming user git's home is set to `/var/lib/git` I expect something like

```
current home »/home/auser«
using git tools at »/var/lib/git«
finally
```

User git has no login shell set (security)

I also tried

```
su -s /bin/bash git - << END_OF_SCRIPT
```

with identical result.

So how can I in a script run a set of script lines as a different user and having its environment set as I would have when executing `su -s /bin/bash git -` on command line?

Even more difficult with `{}`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "current home »$HOME«"
su -s /bin/bash git - << END_OF_SCRIPT
  GitToolsRepo=${HOME}/git-tools
  echo "using git tools at »${GitToolsRepo}«"
END_OF_SCRIPT
echo finally
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape $ in script input block.

Hence correct script will be

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "current home »$HOME«"
sudo -u git -H /bin/bash << END_OF_SCRIPT
  GitToolsRepo=\$HOME/git-tools
  echo "using git tools at »\$GitToolsRepo«"
END_OF_SCRIPT
echo finally
```

Comment: *dough, too obvious. For completeness, added `{}` must be escaped as well, I will add in the question above, if you want to add them in your answers for other readers.

Answer (score 1):

For all readers coming here for the same problem: I figured it is much better to put the part for the other user in a separate script and have either option in one line:

```
sudo -u user bash -c script.sh
sudo -u user script.sh
su user -c "bash script"
```

this it is debuggable and no ugly escaping